# How to add event handler for DropDownList in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I create 2 cascaded DropDownLists as follow,

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SourceType, new SelectList(Model.SourceTypes, "Value", "Text", Model.SourceType))%>

<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Supplier, new SelectList(Model.Suppliers, "Value", "Text", Model.Supplier))%>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#SourceType').change(function () {
            var sourceType = $(this).val();
            var supplierSelect = $('#Supplier');
...
```

It is working fine. The problem is that I need a lots of such pairs of DropDownListFor on one view, and I have to create same number of jquery .change function as the pairs of DropDownListFor because each .change function require unique id. I think there should a way to add event handler for change to each DropDownList so that there is only one jquery function to handle all of them. How to do this? Or is there any other way to achieve this goal? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, you don't need the SelectList if your collection is already a collection of SelectListItem (which yours appears to be).  Just do this:

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Supplier, Model.Suppliers) %>
```

While it's easy to select your dropdowns without referring to a unique id, your problem is that you are creating specific variable names based on these individual items.  You haven't really said how these variables are used, so it's difficult know exactly what you want.. but something like this might work.

You could do something like this, but it relies on the supplier being the next sibling element in the dom tree.  If it's not, you can probably figure out some kind of pattern that would work for you.:

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SourceType, Model.SourceTypes, new {@class = 'source_type'})%>
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Supplier, Model.Suppliers, new {@class = 'supplier'})%>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('select.source_type').change(function () {
        var sourceType = $(this).val();
        var supplierSelect = $(this).next('select.supplier');
    });
</script>
```

Alternatively, you could also get a collection of the source_type classes and supplier classes, loop through them by index and assign them, again, that would assume they were in the correct order in the dom.